# How to know which harddisk has the problem?

Tags: disk

So i got this on `dmesg`:

```
[  227.281863] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  227.281876] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[  227.281881] ata3.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[  227.281884] ata3.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 15
                        res 71/04:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  227.281888] ata3.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[  227.281889] ata3.00: error: { ABRT }
[  227.282295] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
[  227.282298] ata3.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
```

how could i know which one is `ata3`?

my `lsblk`:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda             8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sda1          8:1    0   7.3T  0 part  /media/kyz/wd8tb0
sdb             8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdb1          8:17   0   7.3T  0 part  /media/kyz/wd8tb1
sdc             8:32   0   7.3T  0 disk
├─sdc1          8:33   0   128M  0 part
└─sdc2          8:34   0   7.3T  0 part  /media/kyz/sea8TB
sdd             8:48   0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sdd1          8:49   0   1.9G  0 part
├─sdd2          8:50   0     1K  0 part
└─sdd5          8:53   0 221.7G  0 part
sde             8:64   0  10.9T  0 disk
└─sde1          8:65   0  10.9T  0 part  /media/kyz/wd12tbB
sdf             8:80   0  10.9T  0 disk
└─sdf1          8:81   0  10.9T  0 part  /media/kyz/wd12tbA
sdg             8:96   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdg1          8:97   0   7.3T  0 part  /media/kyz/wd8tbB
sdh             8:112  0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdh1          8:113  0   7.3T  0 part  /media/kyz/wd8tbA
zram0         252:0    0    16G  0 disk  [SWAP]
nvme1n1       259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk  /media/kyz/team512
nvme0n1       259:1    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1   259:2    0 472.9G  0 part  /
├─nvme0n1p2   259:3    0     4G  0 part
│ └─cryptswap 253:0    0     4G  0 crypt
└─nvme0n1p3   259:4    0 476.9G  0 part  /home
```

my `/etc/fstab`:

```
   9   │ # DigitalAlliance 1TB NVMe
  10   │ UUID=4cbbc504-3840-4234-9c55-b912c77aa479  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1
  11   │ #/dev/mapper/cryptswap  none  swap  defaults  0  0
  12   │ UUID=f7451ccb-00b7-437b-918c-8ba9f39a3d0d  /home ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro,exec 0 1
  13   │ /swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
  14   │
  15   │ # WDC WD80EZZX-11CSGA0 (83.H0A03) zero bad sector
  16   │ UUID=afebff04-ed3f-4987-8783-1eb722a22554 /media/kyz/wd8tb0 ext4 noatime,user 0 0
  17   │
  18   │ # WDC WD80EZZX-11CSGA0 (83.H0A03) one bad sector
  19   │ UUID=f7cbc067-26d5-4115-a539-4527a9e834fc /media/kyz/wd8tb1 ext4 noatime,user 0 0
  20   │
  21   │ # WD My Book 25EE (4009)
  22   │ UUID=6f11fb76-9236-4adb-a203-edac39a4d0cd /media/kyz/wd12tbA ext4 noatime,user 0 0
  23   │
  24   │ # WD 12TB WD120EFAX
  25   │ UUID=31f26db7-76b7-4d4d-bedf-a90dd5f196ee /media/kyz/wd12tbB ext4 noatime,user 0 0
  26   │
  27   │ # WD My Book 25EE (4004)
  28   │ UUID=998bec6f-4b11-4bb3-a878-8529c0a8c11d /media/kyz/wd8tbA ext4 noatime,user 0 0
  29   │
  30   │ # WD My Book 25EE (4004)
  31   │ UUID=01492680-b253-45fe-a234-6710e50eb8bf /media/kyz/wd8tbB ext4 noatime,user 0 0
  32   │
  33   │ # Seagate Backup+ Hub BK (D785)
  34   │ UUID=80ECE6F7ECE6E5FE /media/kyz/sea8TB ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
  36   │
  37   │ # 256GB GALAX SSD (broken)
  38   │ #UUID=48c76170-0392-44ce-a8c6-f790673c8f32 /media/kyz/galax250 ext4 noatime,user 0 0
  39   │
  40   │ # 512GB TEAM NVMe
  41   │ /dev/disk/by-uuid/b1080dbf-dad1-4652-8e82-072d41f9a587 /media/kyz/team512 ext4 noatime,user,exec 0 0
```

Comment: `ls -l /sys/block | grep ata3` may give you a clue. Or `print -l /sys/class/ata_port/ata3/device/**/block/*` in zsh

Comment: Read `man smartctl`. It can report on the health of disks and invoke disk self-tests.

Comment: Look at your startup logs - you can watch your system discover its hardware. If you have it, `sudo journalctl  -b 0`,  `man journalctl` is easy, else `sudo less /var/log/syslog`.